# How to get a List from a List Collection? getByTitle returns empty list

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

So I retrieve a bunch of lists from host-web and put them into a listCollection similar to as outlined [here](http://www.mavention.com/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web).

Then I try to access a specific list called `TestList`. However, I can't access it from the listCollection using [getByTitle("TestList")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245065(v=office.15).aspx). It will give me a list with no information from the list I'm retrieving.

However, if I loop through an enumerator until I find a list with the title `TestList`, I can use that.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
var testList = listCollection.getByTitle("TestList");
console.log(testList);
```

But this does?

```
var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();

while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

    oList = listEnumerator.get_current();

    if (oList.get_title() == "TestList") {
        console.log(oList);
    }
}
```

These `console.log` yield the respective outputs. See how the top one doesn't have an `Object` inside the `ClientObjectData`. Why is that? What am I missing?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `getByTitle` method from `sp.js` you should use like this.

```
SP.ListCollection.getByTitle()
```

**NOTE:** With this you will get only the list name not the array of objects.

> Returns the list with the specified title from the collection.

To **get the items** inside the list you should use this method.

```
SP.List.getItems()
```

> Returns a collection of items from the list based on the specified query

From [SP.Listgetitemns docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245102(v=office.15).aspx)

Instead of just:

```
var testList = listCollection.getByTitle("TestList");
```

Try

```
var testList = listCollection.getByTitle("TestList");
listItemCollection = testList.getItems(""); // or use a CAMLQuery to be more specific
context.load(listItemCollection);
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

Then it should be populated and should look like the second example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How does this differ from what I initially tried? The line `SP.ListCollection.getByTitle("TestList");` produces a predictable `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: remove the `L` and put a `l lowerCase`

Comment: it should work with the `l lowerCase` like this  `var testList = SP.listCollection.getByTitle("TestList");`

Comment: Same thing, `var testList = SP.listCollection.getByTitle("blahlblah");` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByTitle' of undefined`.

Comment: seems like `getByTiltle` just return the `title of the list`, to get the itemns you need this method `List.getItems()` check answer update

Comment: I don't think that's right. Look at this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

`getByTitle` is used to get the list in question from the collection returned by `clientContext.get_web().get_lists()` which is what I'm trying to do. `getItems` in then used to get the items of the list you already got using `getByTitle`.

Comment: Well what you say its correct why don't use the method like this.. `testList.getItems()` ?

Comment: Oh! You're right, you're right. I don't show it in the code I posted, but I do `getItems()` on the `oList`, which is why it was different from `testList` in the console.log. I just thought that at the time I did the console.log they should be the same because that was before I did getItems.